# Marshal fails for struct with enum field of custom size

Tags: .net, struct, enums, marshalling

I have a struct which I am trying to Marshal which is defined as follows:

```
enum BBB {BB1 =1, BB2 =2}

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  struct Foo 
  {
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
     public BBB F1;
     public int F2;
     public short F3;
  }
```

Seems like Marshal can't handle this enum field specification and throws an exception: 
**cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.**
If I remove the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)], then marshaling succeeds, but I would like to be able to marshal an enum field as a custom size field not necessarily a 4 byte one.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your enum as `ushort`:

```
enum BBB : ushort {BB1 = 1, BB2 = 2}
```

Comment: WHat about if I am working in F# where I can't specify the size of an enum type: type BBB= |BB1=1 |BB2=2 ?

Comment: @dmg: I'm not too familiar with F#, but my guess would be that it is just not possible then. Not every .NET language supports the same features, and interoperability with native code (and also being able to marshal to native types) hasn't been a goal for F# (in contrast to C#).